# Hiding content in GMail and Outlook not working with Zurb Ink implementation

Tags: html, css, outlook, zurb-ink, responsive-emails

I am experiencing an issue using the Desktop/Mobile show/hide functionality with [Zurb Ink email framework](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php). When I use the CSS below it works correctly in GMail, where the mobile content is hidden and only desktop is shown, but **not** in Outlook. However, with the default Ink CSS (where there is no `!important` flag on the `display: none`) it works in Outlook but **not** in GMail. I am using Outlook 2010.

I have taken some inspiration from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Riveascore/10549334) and i'm using this CSS:

```
div.gmail .show-for-small,
div.gmail .hide-for-desktop {
    display : none !important;
    mso-hide: all !important;
}
```

This is my email markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!-- my inline styles in here -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <div class="gmail">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <table class="body">...</table>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    </div>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    </body>
```

What am I missing?

Zurb has one breakpoint and that being at 600px, so I don't want to change that. The Ink CSS provided by Zurb can be seen [here](https://github.com/zurb/ink/blob/master/css/ink.css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post an answer myself as I eventually got to the bottom of it (for GMail, Mobile iOS and Outlook support at least).

Still sticking with Ink's default classes I changed the visibility classes to:

```
.show-for-small,
.hide-for-desktop {
    display     : none;
    max-height  : 0;   /* Gmail */
    mso-hide    : all;  /* Outlook clients */
    overflow    : hidden;  /* Generic */
    font-size   : 0 !important;  /* Be careful with this one, only use if absolutely required */
    line-height : 0;
    padding     : 0 !important;
}
```

and then in the "mobile" view at the 600px breakpoint I done this to essentially reverse the changes I made above out:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    table[class="body"] .show-for-small,
    table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
        display     : block !important;
        max-height  : 100% !important; /* Gmail */
        mso-hide    : none !important; /* Outlook clients */
        overflow    : visible !important; /* Generic */
        font-size   : 14px !important; /* Be careful with this one, only use if absolutely required */
        line-height : 100% !important;
        height      : 100% !important;
        width       : 100% !important;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone working with Zurb Ink 1 and fingers crossed Zurb sort out this issue in Foundation for Emails on its release.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the logic and possibly sources behind the style changes?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to hide mobile-only content in outlook

```
<!--[if !mso]><\!-->
Mobile Only Content
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Everything inside the if block does not get rendered in Outlook.